# NSSplitView Fixed Splitter on Window Resize?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I'm having a bit of difficulty getting a NSSplitView to behave itself.

What I have at the moment is:

```
NSWindow
   NSView
      NSSplitView
         navView <NSView>
         contentView <NSView>
```

The problem I'm having is with the splitter shifting position when I resize the window.

In the split view delegate I've already got:

```
-(CGFloat)splitView:(NSSplitView *)splitView constrainMaxCoordinate:(CGFloat)proposedMaximumPosition ofSubviewAt:(NSInteger)dividerIndex{
    return 200;
}

-(CGFloat)splitView:(NSSplitView *)splitView constrainMinCoordinate:(CGFloat)proposedMinimumPosition ofSubviewAt:(NSInteger)dividerIndex{
    return 200;

}
```

Despite this the splitter still moved when I resize the window.

if I click ont he splitter, it snaps back to 200px as it should. How can I stop this from moving?

I've tried Autolayout, which is a bit of a nightmare to use, so I've literally disabled it and manually tried to do it with no joy..

Any ideas?

Comment: just to add, this goes totally awry when I programatically set the window frame to accommodate a larger subview in contentView!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've worked it out...

```
-(void)splitView:(NSSplitView *)sender resizeSubviewsWithOldSize:(NSSize)oldSize
{
    CGFloat dividerThickness = [sender dividerThickness];
    NSRect leftRect  = [[[sender subviews] objectAtIndex:0] frame];
    NSRect rightRect = [[[sender subviews] objectAtIndex:1] frame];
    NSRect newFrame  = [sender frame];

    leftRect.size.height = newFrame.size.height;
    leftRect.origin = NSMakePoint(0, 0);
    rightRect.size.width = newFrame.size.width - leftRect.size.width
- dividerThickness;
    rightRect.size.height = newFrame.size.height;
    rightRect.origin.x = leftRect.size.width + dividerThickness;

    [[[sender subviews] objectAtIndex:0] setFrame:leftRect];
    [[[sender subviews] objectAtIndex:1] setFrame:rightRect];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I wrote the above code for Swift and extended it with the possibility to define, whether the left or the right view has to be preferred:

```
var preferringLeftSideOfSplitView = true

func splitView(splitView: NSSplitView, resizeSubviewsWithOldSize oldSize: NSSize) {
    var dividerThickness = splitView.dividerThickness

    var leftRect = splitView.subviews[0].frame
    var rightRect = splitView.subviews[1].frame

    // Resizing and placing the left view
    splitView.subviews[0].setFrameOrigin(NSMakePoint(0, 0))
    if self.preferringLeftSideOfSplitView == true {
        splitView.subviews[0].setFrameSize(NSMakeSize(leftRect.width, splitView.frame.size.height))
    } else {
        splitView.subviews[0].setFrameSize(NSMakeSize(splitView.frame.size.width - rightRect.width - dividerThickness, splitView.frame.size.height))
    }

    // Resizing and placing the right view
    if self.preferringLeftSideOfSplitView == true {
        splitView.subviews[1].setFrameOrigin(NSMakePoint(leftRect.size.width + dividerThickness, 0))
        splitView.subviews[1].setFrameSize(NSMakeSize(splitView.frame.size.width - leftRect.size.width - dividerThickness, splitView.frame.size.height))
    } else {
        splitView.subviews[1].setFrameOrigin(NSMakePoint(splitView.frame.size.width - rightRect.width, 0))
        splitView.subviews[1].setFrameSize(NSMakeSize(rightRect.size.width, splitView.frame.size.height))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)splitView:(NSSplitView *)aSplitView shouldAdjustSizeOfSubview:(NSView *)subview
{
    return subview == rightView;
}
```

add this to your delegate.

if your NSSplitView would contain lefView and rightView, this keeps leftView at a fixed width, and rightView will resize, when resizing the main window.